# Differences in conditions of Afghanistan in 1989 vs. now?

Tags: united-states, democracy, afghanistan, taliban

I'm reading news about the Taliban [gaining control](https://globalnews.ca/news/7969689/taliban-gains-afghanistan/) over the country.

I remember, that Najibullah's government, which was left there by the USSR in 1989 stood for three years after Soviet troops left the country.

Why, in contrast, is President Ghani's administration seemingly more vulnerable?

Comment: Not quite sure about the context here, but after the US invasion, the government of Karzai continued from 2001 to 2014 and Ghani from 2014 to 2021, and total of 20 years.   So why do you describe Ghani's administration as particularly vulnerable?

Comment: @JamesK, because it's cannot survive without constant presence of foreign forces. Sometimes such governments are called "standing on bayonets".

Comment: This question is posted with a not-to-subtle agenda and is the OP simply wants to argue or put forth their own views.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder, how "strong" should point of view be, if being awared of even such slight questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This answer tries to compare the 1989+ and 2021+ *military* situation, as per the stated question.  It doesn't try to compare the different *civil* policies Soviet and US efforts took at the start because that wasn't in the question).

This is going to be hard to know for sure, but there are some possibilities:

- Najibullah got left with quite a bit of armaments, including tanks and planes.  I think the current Afghanistan government is short on air support for example.
- Up to their retreat the Soviets had been not been all that discriminating in their usage of force. 500k-2M civilians killed, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War) (compare to [50K estimate for US occupation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Afghanistan_(2001%E2%80%93present))).  I assume Najibullah followed same counter insurgency doctrine.  Long term, that may not be a winning strategy, but it does slow down losing territory.

  - Relative numbers of civ deaths, unlike what the OP says, were not "made up".  The US occupation was run as a post-Vietnam [COIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterinsurgency) op: try not to kill civilians.  The Soviet occupation, like Vietnam or the Algerian war, was run as traditional Western military subjugation effort:  kill lots, let God sort them out.  (Russia still runs those, see [Grozny in Chechnya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Grozny_(1994%E2%80%9395))).
- The various forces fighting against the Soviets were not all that unified.  the [Northern Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Alliance) for example didn't seem to get along all that well with some of the other groups.  The Talibans seem more cohesive, except for their feud with ISIS (which is pretty limited in scope).
- It *could be* that the Taliban methods are, by necessity, more guerilla-based and less easy to contain by a regular army than the Mujahideen were in the late 80s.  Also, for years, we've had analysises like "[70% of districts are under partial or total Taliban control](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-42863116)".  The USSR may have withdrawn at an earlier phase, where it still held most of the countryside, but had too many losses and was too poor to continue.
- Funding for the mujaheddin **may** have dried up fairly quickly after Soviet withdrawal.  We know one of the tragedies of Afghanistan is how little the US supported its reconstruction in the 90s.  However, it's not clear whether the funding ran dry right after the Soviet withdrawal, or after Najibullah's collapse.  [Operation Cyclone funding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cyclone#Funding) seem to indicate something in between, so perhaps the rebels had reduced firepower and ammo to work with.
- **Ultimately, the duration it takes for the current US backed government to fall is when it does.  For now it isn't looking all that great, but then again maybe Najibullah's prospects weren't that great from the start either so honest news coverage in 1989 might have said the same things.**

#### Nation-building.

Had the OP's question been clearer, I'd have steered clear of the question.  Too complex and press coverage has for years been centered on "sexy military, not boring nation-building".  Here's a partial info dump however:

- In 2001 the US invaded on the cheap.  As Doug Feith states in his so [self-serving book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_and_Decision), they were not into nation building and wanted to keep the US forces low to avoid looking like an occupation force.  Rumsfeld's plan?  [Not to have a plan](https://www.rollingstone.com/politics/politics-news/rumsfeld-threatened-to-fire-anyone-who-planned-iraq-nation-building-90057/).
- At some point incoming reconstruction money, rather than improving  governance, increasingly became diverted into Taliban coffers.  So "building schools" was not the winner it might have been earlier.
- The war was in several phases ([see deaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_military_casualties_in_the_War_in_Afghanistan#Casualties_by_month_and_year)).  In the early days nation-building was not pursued, later on it was probably too late.

  - 2001-2003 On the cheap, secondary, Taliban quiet.  Heavy reliance on airstrikes rather than more dangerous ground troop use.
  - 2003-2008 Increasing US deaths
  - 2009-2013 Post Iraq surge, let's do it in Afghanistan.  Violent phase
  - 2014-2021 Decreasing US operations as troops stay in base.
- Unlike the Soviets, the US initially didn't intend to transform Afghan society, so the nation building *seems* to have been improvised.  It might also have over-relied on Western consultants and specialists, highly paid, and, for the most part, staying in Kabul.  The Soviets **may** have had a bigger core of Afghans truly believing they were bringing in a Marxist paradise.  Ultimately though, maybe imposing Western or even Communist norms on Afghanis was never an acceptable outcome for Afghanis.

**If the real question had been, *Why couldn't the US get a credible goverment going?*,** I *think, maybe,* the answer would lie somewhere in 2001-2005, before sentiment hardened, before [US airstrikes killed too many people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarnak_Farm_incident) and before the US lost its aura of invincibility in the streets of Iraq.  **Wasn't the question that was asked though.**

other readings:

[Nation Building 101](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2004/01/nation-building-101/302862/)

[U.S. officials misled the public about the war in Afghanistan, confidential documents reveal](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2019/investigations/afghanistan-papers/afghanistan-war-confidential-documents/)

Comment: Sorry, but smells like "that's another!". I specifically don't mention numbers of civil deaths - as in both cases they are made up. Generally, I've expected some arguments about civil support comparing, or something  else. But seems that, all arguments are about military force - which is rather irrelevant in this case

Comment: Military affairs are irrelevant to an high-intensity insurgency context?  You don't say.  I suppose the numbers are made up just to make Russia look bad.

Comment: "suppose the numbers are made up just to make Russia look bad" - yes, for me it's an echo of previous cold war. Don't want to hit you in any way, but it's **very** surprising for me to hear such, in fact, fair things from a westerner. And trust me, I appreciate that. "Military affairs are irrelevant" - for me, yes, and let me explain, why. Last Taliban victories are not because of their firepower - but because they are conquering minds of Afgan soldiers and police, who in many cases just surrendering and going home. Of course, military efforts also take place, but only partially

Comment: For example, for me it's enough surprising to compare USSR and US investments. Soviet union build schools, houses, factories. Some districts in Kabul built in those times are now still in usage. And I didn't hear about US massively investing into infrastructure, like mentioned. US do have another approach. But does it works better? That is a core question for me.

Comment: @user2501323 Then you should have asked a different question.  In 1989 and 2021, survival of government is a **military end game**.  Turning around and claiming you meant about nation-building  - **still nowhere to be seen in your question** - is poor form by SE.Po standards in the best of cases .  Yes, sometimes I've "moved the goalposts" on questions myself but I've apologized to the people who answered, not downvoted them.  Had you asked that question, I would have felt even less qualified to answer.

Comment: Now, it looks much better, thanks for the edits, +1